# react-dnd allow drag only from the blank space

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd, react-beautiful-dnd

Here's a sample code for the draggable block :

```
<Draggable key={id} draggableId={id} index={index}>
        {(provided, snapshot) => (
            <Wrapper
                ref={provided.innerRef}
                {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                {...provided.draggableProps}
                isDragging={snapshot.isDragging}
            >
                    <Child id={id} />
            </Wrapper>
        )}
    </Draggable>
```

`Child` takes 90% of the `Wrapper` width. How do I enable drag only from the remaining 10% of the area along the edges ?
I have tried using `onDragStart={(e) => {e.preventDefault();e.stopPropagation();}}` in the Child's div but it doesn't do anything.
Basically I just want to prevent dragging from the child. Any suggestions on how to achieve this ?